# Perl Print to File error

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am rather new to Perl and am trying to combine several .pm files into a single script. Most of the modules copy over just fine, but some have an error where the end of file is reached, but the script keeps printing. Here is an example of the code:

```
$copy_line = 0;
sysopen(FILE, $file_path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0711);
sysopen(MODULE, $module_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXCL);

while(<MODULE>)
{
  my $line = $_;
  if(($line ne "# START\n") and ($copy_line eq 0))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    print FILE "$line";
    $copy_line = 1;
  }
}

close FILE;
close MODULE;
```

Each module has start and end tags to I do not copy any use statements, and so I know when to stop copying. An example of the module is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# START
some code to copy over
some more code to copy
even more code to copy
# END
```

What happens in some files is I see the end tag, followed by repeated code from the module. The output looks something like

```
# START
some code to copy over
some more code to copy
even more code to copy
# END
code to copy
even more code to copy
# END
```

What might be causing this?
Thanks,

-rusty

Comment: Why is half of your conditional commented out? And is there a reason why you're using `sysopen` instead of `open`?

Comment: @friedo Some code was commented out because I mistyped. That has been fixed. And I am using sysopen because that is what I found when I was looking for how to open a file, and create it if necessary (not existing)

Comment: Perl Modules are supposed to be *called*, not mashed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your script:

- You didn't show the whole script; constants like `O_WRONLY` don't exist by default.
- Therefore it may be that you didn't `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your script. This is neccessary to get warned about errors or possible mistakes.
- The `strict` mode requires you to declare all your variables. You can do so with the `my` keyword, e.g. `my $copy_line = 0`.
- Never use `sysopen`, except when you fully understand how `open` works and why it wouldn't be the best choice for a given situation. Considering that I don't have that level of knowledge, I think we'll stick to the normal `open`.

  The `open` takes a variable, a mode, and a filename, like

  ```
  open my $file, "<", $filename;
  ```

  I encourage you to `use autodie` for automatic error handling, otherwise you should do

  ```
  open my $file, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
  ```

  where `$!` contains the reason for the error. You can specify various modes for open, which are modelled after shell redirection operators. Important are: `<` read, `>` write (or create), `>>` append, `|-` write pipe to command, `-|` read pipe from command.
- The `eq` operator tests for string equality. If you want to test for numeric equality, use the `==` operator.
- `if (COND) {} else { STUFF }` could rather be written `unless (COND) {STUFF}`.
- You have successfully implemented some twisted logic that starts copying at the `START` marker. However, you don't stop at the `END`. For stuff like this, the *flip-flop-operator* `..` can be used: It takes two operands, which are arbitrary expressions. The operator returns false until the first operand is true, and remains true until after the second operand returned true. If one operand is a constant integer, it is interpreted as a line number. Thus, the script

  ```
  while (<>) {
    print if 5 .. 10;
  }
  ```

  prints lines number 5–10 inclusive of the input.

  For your problem, you should probably use regexes that match the start and the end marker:

  ```
  while (<>) {
    print if /^ \s* # \s* START/x .. /^ \s* # \s* END/x
  }
  ```

  I'll assume here that you know regexes, but I can add explanations if needed.

  If the readline operator `<>` is used without an operand, it takes the command line arguments of the script, opens them, and reads them in sequence. If no arguments were provided, it uses STDIN.

  This allows for flexible little scripts. The code can be summarized in the command-line oneliner

  ```
  $ perl -ne'print if /^\s*#\s*START/../^\s*#\s*END/' INPUT-FILE1 INPUT-FILE2 >OUTPUT
  ```

  There are two issues with this:

  1. It prints out the start/end markers as well
  2. If a file doesn't contain an `# END`, the next files will be printed out in full until the next `# END` is found.

  We can mitigate issue #2 by testing for the end of file in the termination condition:

  ```
  print if /^\s*#\s*START/ .. (/^\s*#\s*END/ or eof);
  ```

  Issue #1 is slightly more complex; I'd reintroduce a flag for that:

  ```
  my $print_this = 0;

  while (<>) {
    if (/^\s*#\s*END/ or eof) {
        $print_this = 0;
    } elsif ($print_this) {
        print;
    } elsif (/^\s*#\s*START/) {
        $print_this = 1;
    }
  }
  ```

  Partial test case:

  ```
  $ perl -e'
    my $print_this = 0;
    while (<>) {
      if    (/^\s*#\s*END/ or eof) { $print_this = 0 }
      elsif ($print_this)          { print           }
      elsif (/^\s*#\s*START/)      { $print_this = 1 }
    }' <<'__END__'
  no a 1
  no a 2
    # START
  yes b 1
  yes b 2
  yes b 3
  #END
  no c 1
  no c 2
  # START
  yes d 1
   #    END
  no e 1
  __END__
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  yes b 1
  yes b 2
  yes b 3
  yes d 1
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. As you mentioned, I had several things wrong. The fixes were changing the eq to == for integers, and checking for # END. I originally thought I wouldn't have to because of EOF, but it turned out to not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying files without modifying their contents, you should look into `File::Copy` http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html

`File::Copy` is a standard module and is installed along with Perl. For a list of standard modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Standard-Modules

Comment: The problem is that some of the files have use or require at the top, and I do not want those in the merged script